# what is the meaning of "if words have any meaning" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

what is the meaning of "if words have any meaning" in this context?

> In some ways Kane's position is hopelessly illogical. He was on most
>   intimate and affectionate terms with the mother and the two girls,
>   although **if words have any meaning** he thought them to be swindlers
>   living on the credulity of the public. "Kiss Katie for me," he says,
>   and he continually sends love to the mother. Already, young as they
>   were, he had a glimpse of the alcoholic danger to which they were
>   exposed by late hours and promiscuous company. "Tell Katie to drink no
>   champagne, and do you follow the same advice," said he. It was sound
>   counsel, and it would have been well for themselves and for the
>   movement if they had both followed it; but again we must remember
>   their inexperienced youth and the constant temptations.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: Have you looked up _sound_ (adj) and _counsel_ (n) in a dictionary? What does it say?

Comment: Also - we don't use "do" support for questions with the word _be_. _Is "sound" an adjective_, not _does "sound" is an adjective_.

Comment: @Colin Fine sound (adj) counsel (n) means sane or reasonable advice? is it correct for this passage?

Comment: I've rolled back the edits.  You can edit to make a question clearer.  Please **don't** edit to ask a new question.  If you want to ask about "sound counsel", please first check in a dictionary, then if you still need help, post a new question.

Comment: @James K ok dear james k. thanks

Answer (score 1):

A prior sentence says "In these letters Kane continually reproaches Margaret with living in deceit and hypocrisy." Kane had expressed these thoughts in words.

If the thoughts he had expressed in his letters were taken seriously, he thought they were swindlers. So, *if [his] words had any meaning*, then why did he remain "on most intimate and affectionate terms" with them?

Comment: i am partially agree with you. the author says his position is hopelessly illogical because he was in intimate and close relationship with them and he used kind words in his letters but with any purpose, he thought that they deceive people.

Comment: He doesn't use kind words in his letters; "he reproaches Margaret". It is those words whose meaning is belied by his continuing intimacy.

Comment: you are right dear jack but it is ambiguous for me.was kane uncertain about his actions? on one side he reproaches them, on the other side he has a close and affectionate relationship with them. can you clarify please?

Comment: Solesoul, that is the point of the passage: to underline the inconsistency between Kane's words and his actions. Was he being hypocritical? Did he himself have hidden motivations?

Comment: omg. now i can understand it clearly.